# How to invoke AWS cli commands in Lambda function console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to using some aws cli commands in my lambda function. I have created the Lambda layer with AWS packages installed. But still I am getting the error as cannot find the directory aws

Comment: What operations are you wanting to perform? It's probably not a good idea to call the AWS CLI from a Lambda function.

Comment: I am trying to invloke some aws s3 commands for copying some files to  s3 bucket through lambda functions

Comment: Why not sue SDK like boto3?

Comment: While it can be very tempting to call `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync`, it would be advisable to perform the copy operations yourself using boto3. You might be reticent to do so due to lack of familiarity with using boto3, but it will actually be easier (and more supportable) that calling the AWS CLI from an AWS Lambda function.

Comment: Thanks, copy operations using boto3 is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy operations using boto3 is useful.